# Subquery returning multiple columns in duckDB

Tags: python, sql, duckdb

I would like to group by `first_name` and for each `fist_name` get the lowest `age`.
My query which I run in online sql compiler works fine but when I try to use duckDB in python I get error that I try to return multiple columns, but this is exactly what I want:

```
duckdb.BinderException: Binder Error: Subquery returns 2 columns - expected 1
LINE 4: WHERE (first_name, age) IN (
```

My data:

```
customer_id  first_name  last_name  age  country
1            John        Doe        31   USA
2            Robert      Luna       22   USA
3            David       Robinson   22   UK
4            John        Reinhardt  25   UK
5            Betty       Doe        28   UAE
```

sql query runs in online compiler works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer
WHERE (first_name, age) IN (
  SELECT first_name, min(age)
  FROM customer
  GROUP BY first_name
)
```

python script which ends with error

```
import pandas as pd
import duckdb


conn = duckdb.connect('mydb.db')
df = conn.execute("""
SELECT * 
FROM 'customer.csv'
WHERE (first_name, age) IN (
  SELECT first_name, min(age)
  FROM 'customer.csv'
  GROUP BY first_name
)
""").df()

print(df)
```

Is there a issue with duckDB?
Is there some another way to write this query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DuckDB doesn't appear to allow multi-column `IN`. From the [documentation](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/expressions/in):

> The IN operator can also be used with a subquery that returns a single column. See the [subqueries page for more information](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/expressions/subqueries).

Instead of `IN`, use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM 'customer.csv' AS t1
JOIN (
  SELECT first_name, min(age) AS minage
  FROM 'customer.csv'
  GROUP BY first_name
) AS t2 ON t1.first_name = t2.first_name AND t1.age = t2.minage
```